# Proof that $\cos^2(x)\cosh^2(y) + \sin^2(x)\sinh^2(y) = -1 + \sin^2(x) - \sinh^2(y)$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

Could anyone offer a proof that

$$
\cos^2(x)\cosh^2(y) + \sin^2(x)\sinh^2(y) = -1 + \sin^2(x) - \sinh^2(y)?
$$

Comment: Perhaps someone can offer a proof, but not a correct proof, because it isn't true.  Consider the case $x=y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$ and  $\sinh^2 x=1+\cosh^2 x$

so the left hand side is

$$\cos^2 x \cosh^2 x+  \sin^2 x \sinh^2 x=
(1-\sin^2 x) (1+\sinh^2 x)+  \sin^2 x \sinh^2 x=
1-\sin^2 x +\sinh^2 x
$$

So the sign in the question is wrong